# What is the best tech to create an iPad app that both records and plays local videos?

Tags: ios, ipad, html, video, cordova

The key functionality of the app would be 1) recording short videos (typically 20-30 sec), 2) playing the videos 1-5 times right after shooting them (slow motion and pausing are a must) and 3) drawing over the videos, i.e. I'd need an additional data layer on top of the raw video.

I've been studying the HTML5 app platforms (PhoneGap, Titanium) because I'd like to minimize writing native iOS code, but it seems both recording and showing embedded video doesn't work on these platforms. The record-play-edit process is pretty simple, but it needs to be super-smooth and fast.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use JS / HTML5 and then generate the app with eg. Phonegap, then one option could be a custom Phonegap plugin built for "Media capture" and then use HTML5 in creating the app logic.

Objective-C Media Capture:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5

Example Phonegap plugin for Audio Capture:
https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/AudioRecord

More info about Phonegap plugin creation for iOS can be found from Phonegap wiki...